# How to model many-to-many relationships with Apache Spark and Sparkube?

Tags: apache-spark, olap, olap-cube

Let's consider a dataset with a simple many-to-many relationship: bank accounts that can have several owners. The two tables are prepared and available in Apache Spark.

```
Owner,Account
John,A01
John,A02
Bob,A02
Bob,A03
Ana,A03

Account,Balance
A01,2000.0
A02,3000.0
A03,5000.0
```

In Spark if I want to check account balances per user, I start from the "owners" table that I join with the "accounts" table.

```
Owner,Account,Balance (joined)
John,A01,2000.0
John,A02,3000.0
Bob,A02,3000.0
Bob,A03,5000.0
Ana,A03,5000.0
```

This way I can sum balances and the sums per owner are correct. But the total sum would be wrong, because single accounts appear multiple times.

```
Owner,Balance
John, 5000.0
Bob, 8000.0
Ana, 5000.0
Total (wrong), 18000.0
```

If I want the total amount of money in the bank, I run an aggregation directly on "accounts" table.

```
Total (right), 10000.0
```

Now I would like to expose my Spark dataset as an OLAP cube with [Sparkube](https://www.activeviam.com/en/sparkube) so that business users can make their own dashboards in Excel and Tableau. Is there a way to make Sparkube understand the many-to-many relationship and expose both the right aggregates per owner and the right totals.

Answer (score 0):

Sparkube exposes **one** dataset as a multidimensional cube. So a quick solution for this use case is to expose two cubes, one for the 'account' dataset and one for the 'owner' dataset (joined with accounts). Then when you make your dashboards, use the right cube for the right level of aggregation.

```
import com.activeviam.sparkube._
new Sparkube()
    .fromDataset(account)
    .withName("accounts_v1")
    .expose()

val owners = owner.join(account, "Account")
new Sparkube()
    .fromDataset(owners)
    .withName("owners")
    .expose()
```

That's not great though, if you give this to end users they will make mistakes and display wrong totals.

Since version **0.1.6** [Sparkube](https://activeviam.com/en/sparkube) natively supports [Spark arrays](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/types/ArrayType.html), and that's the right way to model simple many-to-many relationships within one single dataset. Combine the two tables with Spark and for each account collect the owners in an array:

```
val dataset = owner
    .join(account, "Account")
    .groupBy("Account")
    .agg(collect_list("Owner").as("Owners"))
    .join(account, "Account")

dataset.show()

+-------+-----------+-------+
|Account|     Owners|Balance|
+-------+-----------+-------+
|    A01|     [John]| 2000.0|
|    A03| [Bob, Ana]| 5000.0|
|    A02|[John, Bob]| 3000.0|
+-------+-----------+-------+

new Sparkube()
    .fromDataset(dataset)
    .withName("accounts_v2")
    .expose()
```

When you browse this latest cube from Excel, Tableau or ActiveUI, the aggregates will be right whatever the aggregation level and filter.

[image]